# Trouble disabling button using useRef inputs and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component with four ref objects as below.

```
  const lastNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const firstNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const emailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const passwordRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

i also have a different button component that takes in a disabled flag as a prop.

```
<SignInOrSignUpButton
  disabled={false}
  icon={faGear}
  isLoading={isLoading}
  onClick={handleSignUp}
  text="Create Account"
/>
```

I'm trying to disable the button when any of my inputs are empty. Here is what i tried first
I tried checking if any of the input`s value`s length is 0 implying the input is empty. This didn't work

```
<SignInOrSignUpButton
  disabled={
    lastNameRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
    firstNameRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
    emailRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
    passwordRef.current?.value.length === 0
  }
  icon={faGear}
  isLoading={isLoading}
  onClick={handleSignUp}
  text="Create Account"
/>
```

I also tried the useState useEffect combination but that also didn't work.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      lastNameRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
      firstNameRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
      emailRef.current?.value.length === 0 ||
      passwordRef.current?.value.length === 0
    ) {
      setIsButtonDisabled(true);
    } else {
      setIsButtonDisabled(false);
    }
  }, [
    lastNameRef.current?.value,
    firstNameRef.current?.value,
    emailRef.current?.value,
    passwordRef.current?.value,
  ]);


<SignInOrSignUpButton
  disabled={isButtonDisabled}
  icon={faGear}
  isLoading={isLoading}
  onClick={handleSignUp}
  text="Create Account"
/>
```

Please help.

Comment: Consider not using the values from the refs directly and instead putting the values into state?

Comment: The issue here is that updating `ref`s doesn't cause the component to re-render and the three different approaches you took would require the component to re-render in order to display the button as disabled.

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `ref`s for the inputs?

Comment: @VictorSantizo yes i would prefer refs

Comment: @VictorSantizo the last way i did it i updated state. what was wrong with that then?

Comment: not really, that effect will never run due to the ref not changing

Comment: @evolutionxbox example in code if you do not mind?

Comment: This is covered in the react docs https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because React doesn't re-render your component. `useRef` is used as a plain javascript object that persists between renders, but changing it doesn't cause a re-render as modifying any nested properties.

I would go with simple states to achieve whatever you are trying, converting the inputs from uncontrolled to controlled input.
Here are the [official React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that updating `ref`s doesn't cause the component to re-render and the three different approaches you took would require the component to re-render in order to display the button as disabled.

Although the [docs](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#best-practices-for-refs) recommend using refs just as an "escape hatch", if you are forced to keep using `ref`s instead of state. Add another ref for the `button`.

```
const buttonRef = useRef(null);
```

Create a function to change the `disabled` attribute for the `button`:

```
const enableButton = () => {
  if (inputRef?.current?.value.length === 0) {
    if (buttonRef.current) {
      buttonRef.current.disabled = true;
    }
  } else {
    if (buttonRef.current) {
      buttonRef.current.disabled = false;
    }
  }
};
```

So each `<input>` will update the `buttonRef` when there's a change. Example:

```
<input type="text" ref={THE_INPUT_REF} onChange={() => enableButton()}/>
```

Create a function to return true/false to set the initial disabled value for the button

```
const isInitiallyDisabled = () => {
    if (inputRef?.current?.value.length > 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```

Pass the `buttonRef` ref to your button component. Note: since you're using your own function component you will have to use `forwardRef` within the component to pass the `buttonRef`

```
<SignInOrSignUpButton
  ref={buttonRef}
  disabled={isInitiallyDisabled()}
  icon={faGear}
  isLoading={isLoading}
  onClick={handleSignUp}
  text="Create Account"
/>
```

Comment: Won't that cause unnecessary rerenders of my component? For example, an input taking in an email address that is 14 characters long. Isn`t it unnecessary to rerender that component that many times?

Comment: Just updated the answer to use no state variables at all. The performance that you might obtain from not re-rendering is going to be negligible and it makes the code harder to maintain and understand